# Step by step tutorial to use SAP. net Connector with VS 2008

Tags: c#, .net, sap-dotnet-connector

I have found many example on the Internet but many are old (VS 2003, SAP. Net Connector 2.0 where the current is 3.0).

I wonder how to use SAP. NET Connector.

What files should I install?

References which add to the project?

How to add the provider to create a connection in Server Explorer?

Comment: The documantation is in: http://service.sap.com/connectors A sap user is needed.

Comment: Ok, but whats is SAP user?

Comment: If you need to setup multiple RfcServers or RfcDestinations hosted in a process, you should run like hell as the NCO is a static nightmare and disallows this despite having *Manager classes with internal collections.

Answer (score 88):

### An example using vs2010 and SAP .NET Connector 3.0

Requirements:

- Visual Studio .NET 2010 (the free c# Express edition is fine)
- SAP .NET Connector 3.0 (you can usually obtain it from your client for the project at hand)

### Installation

Identify the correct version for your platform. You might have something along the following:

[image]

.. for a Windows 7 64-bit installation, we'll use `sapnco30dotnet40P_12-20007348.zip`.

Expand the archive, and start the `.msi` installation file.

[image]

.. follow the installation procedure, leaving all default options (next.. next.. next.. finish).

### Referencing

Open Visual Studio and create a new project (or open your own).

In the `Solution Explorer` panel, usually to your right, right-click on `References` and choose `Add Reference`:

[image]

.. then, select the `Browse` tab, navigate to the SAP Connector installation folder, and select both `sapnco.dll` and `sapnco_utils.dll` :

[image]

Now that you've correctly referenced the SAP .NET Connector in your Visual Studio project, you can write code for it.

### Connecting

Start by creating a destination configuration class (replace the connection parameters with the ones you're given by your client):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SAP.Middleware.Connector; // your sap connector

namespace WindowsFormsSapApplication1
{
    public class ECCDestinationConfig : IDestinationConfiguration
    {

        public bool ChangeEventsSupported()
        {
            return false;
        }

        public event RfcDestinationManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler ConfigurationChanged;

        public RfcConfigParameters GetParameters(string destinationName)
        {

            RfcConfigParameters parms = new RfcConfigParameters();

            if (destinationName.Equals("mySAPdestination"))
            {
                parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, "sapnode.mycompany.net");
                parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, "21");
                parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemID, "CF1");
                parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.User, "mySAPuser");
                parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Password, "mySAPpassword");
                parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Client, "100");
                parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Language, "EN"); 
                parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PoolSize, "5");
            }
            return parms;

        }
    }
}
```

.. then, connect to SAP and call a function. Suppose that you want to retrieve the list of companies, using the `BAPI_COMPANYCODE_GETLIST` SAP function:

```
    public void GetCompanies() {

        ECCDestinationConfig cfg = new ECCDestinationConfig();

        RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(cfg);

        RfcDestination dest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("mySAPdestination");

        RfcRepository repo = dest.Repository;

        IRfcFunction testfn = repo.CreateFunction("BAPI_COMPANYCODE_GETLIST");

        testfn.Invoke(dest);

        var companyCodeList = testfn.GetTable("COMPANYCODE_LIST");

        // companyCodeList now contains a table with companies and codes

    }
```

### Making life easier

In the above example, the `GetTable` function returns a *SAP* table which you may like, or not. There's a handy extension that transforms that table in a familiar .NET `DataTable`, as follows:

```
public static class IRfcTableExtentions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts SAP table to .NET DataTable table
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sapTable">The SAP table to convert.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IRfcTable sapTable, string name)
    {
        DataTable adoTable = new DataTable(name);
        //... Create ADO.Net table.
        for (int liElement = 0; liElement < sapTable.ElementCount; liElement++)
        {
            RfcElementMetadata metadata = sapTable.GetElementMetadata(liElement);
            adoTable.Columns.Add(metadata.Name, GetDataType(metadata.DataType));
        }

        //Transfer rows from SAP Table ADO.Net table.
        foreach (IRfcStructure row in sapTable)
        {
            DataRow ldr = adoTable.NewRow();
            for (int liElement = 0; liElement < sapTable.ElementCount; liElement++)
            {
                RfcElementMetadata metadata = sapTable.GetElementMetadata(liElement);

                switch (metadata.DataType)
                {
                    case RfcDataType.DATE:
                        ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetString(metadata.Name).Substring(0, 4) + row.GetString(metadata.Name).Substring(5, 2) + row.GetString(metadata.Name).Substring(8, 2);
                        break;
                    case RfcDataType.BCD:
                        ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetDecimal(metadata.Name);
                        break;
                    case RfcDataType.CHAR:
                        ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetString(metadata.Name);
                        break;
                    case RfcDataType.STRING:
                        ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetString(metadata.Name);
                        break;
                    case RfcDataType.INT2:
                        ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetInt(metadata.Name);
                        break;
                    case RfcDataType.INT4:
                        ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetInt(metadata.Name);
                        break;
                    case RfcDataType.FLOAT:
                        ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetDouble(metadata.Name);
                        break;
                    default:
                        ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetString(metadata.Name);
                        break;
                }
            }
            adoTable.Rows.Add(ldr);
        }
        return adoTable;
    }

    private static Type GetDataType(RfcDataType rfcDataType)
    {
        switch (rfcDataType)
        {
            case RfcDataType.DATE:
                return typeof(string);
            case RfcDataType.CHAR:
                return typeof(string);
            case RfcDataType.STRING:
                return typeof(string);
            case RfcDataType.BCD:
                return typeof(decimal);
            case RfcDataType.INT2:
                return typeof(int);
            case RfcDataType.INT4:
                return typeof(int);
            case RfcDataType.FLOAT:
                return typeof(double);
            default:
                return typeof(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: http://antswift.wordpress.com/2011/12/22/irfctable-to-net-datatable-extention-method/

After adding the above extension, you can now transform the result into a `DataTable`:

```
// get the regular SAP structured table..
var companyCodeList = testfn.GetTable("COMPANYCODE_LIST");

// turn it into a DataTable..
var companyDataTable = companyCodeList.ToDataTable();

// use it
SomeForm.DataGridView.DataSource=companyDataTable;
```

### Notes

- While this example is based on vs2010, other Visual Studio editions should run just fine.
- It *appears* that SAP function names in the Connector should be always UPPERCASE.
- If you get the SAP Connector architecture wrong, e.g. you install the 64bit version and then try to compile for 32-bit x86, you will get an error like: *"Could not load file or assembly 'sapnco, Version=3.0.0.42, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50436dca5c7f7d23' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."* This is normal; just install the correct version.

### Additional Reading

- http://service.sap.com/connectors
- http://antswift.wordpress.com/2011/12/22/connecting-to-sap-and-retrieving-data-using-version-3-0-of-the-sap-net-connector/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/521485/SAP-Integration-with-Net-4-0-SAP-Connection-Manage
- http://www.dataxstream.com/2011/11/nco-3-rfc-client-vb-net-step-by-step/

Comment: Would it be possible to change the accepted answer since the selected answer has 0 votes and this answer has 12 up-votes and more accurately answers the question?