# Hibernate SAP integration

Tags: spring, hibernate, sap, hibernate-mapping, spring-orm

Can we integrate Hibernate and SAP? I do have integrated a few databases with Hibernate. Since am not aware of SAP, I want to know if there is any support provided by Hibernate to integrate it with the SAP.

Comment: You could connect to an underlying SAP database which might be Oracle, IBM DB2, MySQL, etc., however only for a `read-only` access. Changes are not allowed as the business logic resides in the application layer (technically ABAP code in the SAP application server). Therefore surely writing to a database would be a disaster especially for SAP standard transparent tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know I don't think that exists. SAP has its own data mapping strategy known as [Open SQL](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/fc/eb3969358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm) and also provides special functions to insert, update and delete data that also ensure data consistency, those functions are called [BAPI](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/BAPI) and unless you have an [SAP connector](https://websmp206.sap-ag.de/public/connectors) to call these BAPIs then there's not much you can do. For more reference check this [.Net connector example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300049/step-by-step-tutorial-to-use-sap-net-connector-with-vs-2008).

Sure you can make a connection directly (if the system administrator and/or DBA let you) to the database however is not advisable and is very dangerous because you could create inconsistencies in the system. Please do not try this approach.

However you can make use of software like the connectors I mentioned before or you could use the SAP interface system. You can find more information on this issue checking out the terms [ALE and IDocs](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/ALE+and+IDocs).

Another strategy is using an intermediate table on a database where you and SAP take and write data and with some controls communicate each other but on this issue you would use a BAPI in case of using a standard table or making a custom table (Z table) where you have more freedom to make your own changes.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

No, because SAP is not a database.

SAP is a software which is backed by a database. It does support several different RDBMS systems. Theoretically you could use Hibernate to access the database which backs your SAP system, but this is likely not a very good idea. Both hibernate and SAP are built on the assumption that they have exclusive access to the database. Having another application make changes to the DB without them knowing can lead to all kinds of obscure problems.

There are, however, several other methods to integrate SAP into your business processes, like calling BAPI function models using SAPs proprietary RFC protocol, communicating via IDocs, Batch-Input, SOAP webservices and many more.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of the SAP system as a database as in RDBMS: No, you can't, because it isn't - as others have pointed out.

If you want to use something Hibernate-like stuff to access a backend system, you might want to take a look at [Hibersap](http://hibersap.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You can say SAP has built its own "Hibernate framework" in the Application Layer called OpenSQL( I guess this was built ages before Hibernate ). So SAP applications(ERP/CRM/SRM etc.) can communicate with any database type. So think of it like, SAP has a dialect for different databases.

But when you configure SAP application to use a Database, that database is locked down by SAP and you should not even try to hack it to directly update the database using direct SQL or any other framework like Hibernate. SAP does 100s of validations and checks before it saves the data into the database, you would be bypassing these checks if you are updating the database directly.

I think no organisation would allow you to do it in a production environment and if they allow you to, they don't need SAP.

SAP owns some database products like maxDB, sybase, HANA etc..Hibernate has the dialects for these products.  Hibernate with HANA could be interesting.