# Create Type T (sm59) program with .net

Tags: c#, saprfc

I have to implement a .net program that allow to pass data from SAP (sm59) to other systems. It is a MUST to use sm59, Connection type T, program ID...

The best solution i've found is:

> 1. Create a SAP Connector Class - Application ( Under Visual C# Projects ) and give the RFC name and build the application.
> 2. Inside this application, write your .net code as per your requirement.
> 3. After completed, this application will create an exe file ( Under the folder bin\release ).
> 4. You need to pass the command line parameters to execute this exe file. Command line parameters are
>    -a -g<SAP Server Name/IP Address> -X
>    For example:-aREG -gSAPSER1 -xSAPGW00
> 5. Create a RFC destination in SM59, Under TCP/IP.
>    Technical Settings --> Activation Type --> Registered Server Program ( Need to be selected ).
>    Program ID must be your registeration name : REG
>    Gateway Options are
>    Gateway Host:SAPSER1
>    Gateway Service:SAPGW00
> 6. Write an ABAP program to call the RFC with destination as created in 5th setp.
> 7. The exe file should run in the same domain/LAN of your SAP server. You can test the connection in SM59.

The .NET application must implement some interface? rfc on this way its so simple to call .exe with params? this is the correct way to implement or i forget/not found something?

Thanks

Comment: What is the question, I have read this 4 times, and I'm still not clear on what you need.

Comment: is this the correct way to extract data from SAP to a .NET code? (i've never worked with SAP before)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Step by step tutorial to use SAP. net Connector with VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300049/step-by-step-tutorial-to-use-sap-net-connector-with-vs-2008)