# Inserts, updates and deletes to SAP tables

Tags: c#, bapi, sap-dotnet-connector

Would someone post me an example C# code to update a table record in SAP Subsystem using BAPIs? I was able to select record from a SAP table using the example explained in the below link
[Step by step tutorial to use SAP. net Connector with VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300049/step-by-step-tutorial-to-use-sap-net-connector-with-vs-2008).

I checked couple of threads in the forums for this but couldn't get an understandable notes regarding the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your question contains multiple parts, let me try to explain each of them.

First of all, your need is to define which BAPI you need to call to update your SAP table. When you found it, make sure it is RFC-enabled. If it isn't you'll need to create a wrapper function module that is RFC-enabled and that simply calls this BAPI.

When you've found the BAPI, actually calling it using the .net Connector is quite simple. There's a very complete example right here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/824928/SAP-Net-Connector-NCo-Example

But overall, you need to setup your connection("destination") to SAP using the RfcDestinationManager. When your destination is setup, you retrieve the repository and then the function module like this:

```
rfcDestination = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination(destinationName);
RfcRepository rfcRepository = rfcDestination.Repository;
IRfcFunction rfcFunction = rfcRespository.CreateFunction("BAPI_WHATEVER");
```

Then you can fill the function module's parameters using the SetValue function:

```
rfcFunction.SetValue("fieldName", value);
```

When you're done with the parameters, you call the Invoke function to actually do the call.

```
rfcFunction.Invoke(rfcDestination);
```

After the call, you can use GetValue function or the Tables property to retrieve the returning values:

```
var value = rfcFunction.GetValue("fieldName");
```

With that you should have everything you need to call a BAPI that updates an SAP table.