# Getting data from SAP to C# with TABLE_ENTRIES_GET_VIA_RFC

Tags: c#, .net, saprfc, sap-dotnet-connector

I have written some code for a program that is using the RFC .NET Connector to get the data from an SAP Server to my C# program. I have done some research what module you should use to get data from the server but I couldn't find out how to use the module.

`RFCConnector.cs`:

```
class RFCConnector
{
    RfcDestination dest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("SAPServer");

    public void Ping()
    {
        dest.Ping();
        Console.WriteLine("Ping erfolgreich.");
    }

    public void GetData(string module)
    {
        IRfcFunction function = dest.Repository.CreateFunction(module);
        Console.WriteLine("Verbindung erfolgreich aufgebaut zu Module: " + module);
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RFCConnector connector = new RFCConnector();

        connector.Ping();

        connector.GetData("TABLE_ENTRIES_GET_VIA_RFC");
    }
}
```

In the [SAP .NET Connector Programming Guide](https://support.sap.com/content/dam/support/en_us/library/ssp/products/connectors/msnet/dotnet_connector_30_programming_guide.pdf), it tells you can get access to the fields of a table with this code:

```
IRfcTable addresses = function["ADDRESSES"].GetTable();
Console.WriteLine("STREET");
for (int index = 0; index < addresses.RowCount; ++index)
{
    Console.WriteLine(addresses[index]["STREET"].GetString());
}
```

The problem is when I put that code into my program I get this error:

> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcInvalidParameterException: "Element ADDRESSES of container metadata TABLE_ENTRIES_GET_VIA_RFC unknown"

Comment: The RFM TABLE_ENTRIES_GET_VIA_RFC also falls under these RFC_READ_TABLE variants which I mentioned in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51464052/7337102

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need Help at Getting data from SAP to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382441/need-help-at-getting-data-from-sap-to-c-sharp)